# What does it mean when a class comes right after an id:

Tags: css

What does it mean in css when a class comes right after an id (there is no space between them)? such as this:

```
#bgimage.header-image
```

Thanks

Comment: it means an element with both that id and class - if there is no space between selectors it means that it must have both.  You may find this useful: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: It means what the basic syntax rules of the language say it means. This is a poorly researched question IMO.

Answer (score 2):

It means that this formula will be used for the same element, such as

```
<div id="bgimage" class="header-image"></div>
```

If you'll make space between #bgimage and .header-image then it will be used to:

```
<div id="bgimage"><div class="header-image"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It means an element with id and class at the same time. Eg:

```
<div id="bgimage" class="header-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below example for difference between the selectors.

```css
/* _class should be a child of _id */
#_id ._class{
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* It should have both id and class */
#_id._class{
  background: #faa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="_id">
  <div class="_class">
      Box 1
  </div>
</div>


<div class="_class" id="_id">
  Box 2
</div>
```